# Cannot connect to Google Adwords ColdFusion API

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, google-ads-api

Is anyone using the ColdFusion API for Google Adwords? I'm having a terrible time getting it to work and know I'm probably the problem. Any advice, pointers would really help because I'm beyond stuck.
I'll owe you one!

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What have you tried and what error message(s) are you getting?

Comment: Hey @Miguel-F 
I put in my credentials into config.cfm but then get an error: Detail  If the component name is specified as a return type, it is possible that either a definition file for the component cannot be found or is not accessible.
Message  The value returned from the get function is not of type ServicedAccountGraph.

Comment: When I try to add a campaign, I get an error because it can't find the service from this code on campaignservice.cfc line 125 -- 

<!--- call webservice and get back xml response from the google adwords api--->
  <cfset stResponse=getService().callWebService("CampaignService",this)>

Comment: This problem is with the AdwordsServiceUrl on line 39 in service.cfc -- the values for sandbox and production return "No service was found."

I have the following for production and sandbox. What is the correct url?
https://adwords-sandbox.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201109/CampaignService

https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201109/CampaignService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on October 25th 2012 v201109 went to sunset and can no longer be used. Martin Orth's solution still calls v201109 and even if you change everything to v201209 (the current version) there are enough changes to the API that the CF library no longer works. I tried and tried and tried to contact Martin but no returned emails. So essentially, DON'T TRY TO USE ColdFusion API -- it will not work without the changes. If someone has more information on this, let me know but for now nothing works.